# The placement of "actually"

Tags: meaning, adverbs, adverb-position

What is the difference in meaning between the two sentences below?

> The conference was **actually** quite interesting.
>
> **Actually**, the conference was quite interesting.

Thank you!

Comment: There are other placement options too:: *The conference was quite interesting, actually.* / *The conference actually was quite interesting.*

Comment: There is no rule I know of to cover this.  Whatever the order, this particular adverb conveys (to me, at least, an air of surprise, as if I had been expecting it to be dull or uninteresting.

Comment: The second sentence sounds to me like a response to some comment to the contrary, whereas the first sentence stands on its own.

Comment: More interesting is whether 'Actually, the conference was interesting' and 'The conference was actually interesting' are as closely synonymous. Here, in the second sentence,  the surprise factor, the 'in spite of what we/I expected' mitigator/contrastive, is IMO far stronger.

Comment: I often view "actually" as a mere word filler when it appears as the opening word in a sentence, unless, of course, the sentence is in response to a previous statement, in which case it would serve as a conjunctive adverb joining the current statement to the previous one.

Comment: There is no difference in meaning. The meaning of _actually_ refers to the entire sentence, and therefore has no particular place to sit. The choice of when to say it in the course of the sentence is one of timing, rather than meaning: when in understanding the sentence does the speaker want the listener to become aware of the speaker's initial expectations which were contradicted?